# Excel VBA Format(<Date>, "mmmmm-yy") not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba, date-formatting

I have cells in my excel sheet that contain a date.

The display format for these cells is a custom format "mmmmm-yy"
so that the date "7/1/16" appears as "S-16". This works format works on the excel sheet, however, in VBA I try to call the Format() function on these cells, it does not yield the same format.

```
Format( <Date_Cell> , "mmmmm-yy")
```

Gives

```
"April4-16"
```

on the chart, for example.

Why does the `Format` function not behave the same as formatting a date cell?

Edit: According to the office support website, [Format a date the way you want](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e), I am using the correct format, but it is not producing the result the website claims it should.

Edit2: Turns out cell date formatting works differently than the VBA Format function, as the selected answer points out.

Comment: You have one too many `m` in the month part, only use 4.

Comment: No, that produces the full month name "June-16" vs "J-16". According to the office support website, 5 'm's is correct [Format a date the way you want](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of the format symbols of the VBA function [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) and the [Excel Date Format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e?CorrelationId=8223f6e6-2720-4a88-9c46-92aedc0ae9e2&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102809474#__toc320186183) are not 100% identically.

You could use the worksheet function `TEXT` like:

```
Application.Text( <Date_Cell> , "mmmmm-yy")
```

to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 4):

The VBA `Format` function doesn't support the "mmmmm" format as first letter of the month (see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) for supported formats). Your output is actually parsing as "mmmm" (month name), then "m" (month number).  If you only need the first letter of the month, you'll need to parse it out manually:

```
Left$(MonthName(Month(<Date_Cell>)), 1) & "-" & Right$(CStr(Year(<Date_Cell>)), 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

One more option:

Change the number format of the cell:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "mmmmm-yy"
```